# Error finding custom protobuf plugin

Tags: python, macos, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

When I try to generate code from `.proto` files using plugins I've downloaded, it works. For example, using the following works:

`protoc --python_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-python=$GOPATH/bin/protoc-gen-python ./hello.proto`

and so does

```
protoc --go_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-go=$GOPATH/bin/protoc-gen-go ./hello.proto
```

These commands generate proper stubs (pretty much does what the plugin wants them to do).
However, the following gives an error:

`protoc --custom_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-custom=my-plugin.py ./hello.proto`

The error simply says

`my-plugin.py: program not found or is not executable
--custom_out: protoc-gen-custom: Plugin failed with status code 1.`

even though `my-plugin.py` is in my current directory

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my python script wasn't an executable; I had to add the following to the top:
`#!/usr/bin/env python`